# call a node child with condition on chrome console

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, console

At the first, I have to say sorry if my question is stupid. because I am new to code!

I saw a webpage that in source code we have some node js like this

```
<script>window.INITIAL_HYDRATION_DATA={"page":{"data":{"notFound":false,"item":{"id":"534",......
```

I just read `id` content with the web browser console.
I used the below code.

```
window.INITIAL_HYDRATION_DATA.page.data.item
```

I got `undefined`
I think it related to `"notFound":false`. could you help me with how to can get id's content from console?

Comment: It works for me. Why would another property in the `data` object interfere with accessing the `item` property?

Comment: What do you see if you do just type `window.INITIAL_HYDRATION_DATA.page.data`?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your reply. its work. I just restart Chrome!